# how to simplify pop, push and unshift?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects and I would like to extract the object keys and put them in an array of possible object keys. This is the array of objects I started with :

```
const data = [
    {
        name: "Joe",
        age: 23,
        job: "Artist",
        hoby: "Drawing",
    },
    {
        name: "Michael",
        age: 21,
        job: "Engineer",
        hoby: "Fishing",
    },
    {
        name: "Jenifer",
        age: 22,
        job: "Dentist",
        hoby: "Gardening",
    },
]
```

I would like to get the following output :

```
{ header: [ 'number', 'name', 'age', 'job', 'hoby' ],
   data:
   [ { name: 'Joe', age: 23, job: 'Artist', hoby: 'Drawing' },
      { name: 'Michael', age: 21, job: 'Engineer', hoby: 'Fishing' },
      { name: 'Jenifer', age: 22, job: 'Dentist', hoby: 'Gardening' } 
   ] }
```

Right now I'm using the following code to accomplish this :

```
data.unshift(header);
data.pop(data)
data.pop(data)
data.pop(data)
data.push(data1);
```

But it isn't returning what I would like it to return. Does anyone know an answer to my question. Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: what is the wanted result after all?

Comment: Please add all the code you have, the example doesn't procude "wkwkw". Or that means "hahaha" ..?

Comment: `output = { header, data }`?

Comment: see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: He seems to be asking us to do his course work for him, which has this contrived situation of having to use the pop, push etc functions.  I'd rather leave him to it to be honest.

Comment: actually not only asks you for do my course work, its a petty mind,

i already done with my code, but i wannas explore more, and i ask if one of you could make it simply. i hope its clear

output that i want is like in the question,

add header property, with array values to the original data, and add property data: ... to the object

and wrap with {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
result = {
  header: [],
  data: data
};

for(const record of data) {
  for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(record)) {
     if(!result.header.includes(key)) {
       result.header.push(key)
     }
  }
}

console.log(result)
```

But i dont get where your header `number` comes from...?

Comment: woooww its genius, thans sascha, i will learn this code

Comment: There's even some room for improvement:
``for(const key of Object.keys(record)``
Use that for i little more lightweight loop :)

Comment: its cant work sascha

Comment: please be more specific @achmadrobbi

Comment: result1 = {
    header: [],
    data: data
  };
  
  
  for(const key of Object.keys(record)) {

    for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(record)) {

       if(!result.header.includes(key)) {
         result.header.push(key)
       }
    }
  }
  
  console.log(result1)

i replace the lopping code like this, but error says, record its undefined

Comment: Use ``Object.keys()`` instead of ``Object.entries()`` on the original code. You still need to loop the data array: ``for(const record of data) {``

Comment: wah, thanks sascha its work, i will learn it, thanks once again